# How to write complicated nested schema.xml in solr?

Tags: solr

I have a nested json like this .How to write `schema.xml` for it?

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "lastChangedUserId": "nits.gyl",
  "createdDtmInMilliSeconds": "1584686066767",
  "data": {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "AddressDTO",
    "field1": {
      "op": "CHANGED",
      "oldVal": "1234",
      "newVal": "1235"
    },
    "field2": {
      "op": "CHANGED",
      "oldVal": "1234",
      "newVal": "1235"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Usually you want to restructure your data to fit with a flatter document model when indexing it into Solr. Solr has traditionally not been well suited for arbitrary JSON structures (i.e. hierarchical data). See https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/transforming-and-indexing-custom-json.html

Comment: thanks @MatsLindh. But in case if I want to create schema like this is it possible in solr?